# How can I stop my MIPS .data section's char variables from being overwritten?

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

In my MIPS program's .data section, I define two char variables, d and h.

```
.data
d:  .word   
h:  .word
```

In my .text section, I attempt to set the value of d to 'i' and the value of h to 'k'.

```
.text

#setting d = to 'i'
la $s0, d
li $s1, 'i'
sb $s1, 0($s0)

#setting h =  to 'x'
la $s0, h
li $s1, 'x'
sb $s1, 0($s0)
```

However, when I print out the value of d and the value of h afterward, they are both 'x'.

```
#printing d
lb $a0, d
li $v0, 11
syscall

#printing h
lb $a0, h
li $v0, 11
syscall
```

I seem to be overwriting the value of 'i.' What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never give `d` and `h` initial values, so no space is reserved for them, hence they both have the same address.

You can see this by looking at the addresses that are used after you assemble in MARS. In QtSPIM this wouldn't even assemble because it requires you to specify an initial value.

To fix this, change those two variable declarations to

```
d:  .word 0  
h:  .word 0
```